# Trying to parse JSON into swift3 and display into UILabel

Tags: ios, json, swift3

how to parse this data into swift3 and display into UILabel.

please someone help me through this as I'm new to swift and working on my first project. thanks in advance.

```
{
    “Driver_Details” :[
   {
        “Staff_ID”:2,
        “Staff_Name”:”Pratyush”,
        “Student_ID”:1
        “Route_Number”:”1A”
        “Route_Name”:”Guindy”
        “Stop_Name”:”Velachery”
        “Distance_from_School”:3,
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your swift-part of the code?

Comment: I haven't tried yet because I don't know from where should I begin please help me :(

Comment: Then, please, first check tutorials. Like (directly about JSON/Swift) http://roadfiresoftware.com/2016/12/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-3/ or (In General) https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/topics

Comment: @FieryCat ok thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If you are opening this as a local file from your Documents folder as DriverDetails.json you can try this:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DriverDetails", ofType: "json") { 
    do { 
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe) 
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
            if let jsonDriverDetails = json["Driver_Details"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                // Here you have an array of DriverDetails Dictionaries
                for jsonDriverDetail in jsonDriverDetails {
                    // Iterating through each Dictionary you can access the values using the key
                    staffNameLabel.text = jsonDriverDetails["Staff_Name"] as? String
                }
            }
         }
     } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) } 
 }
```

Comment: hey thanks mate but this data is coming from the URL for that what should I change into your code?

Comment: Are you using AlamoFire?

Comment: No its very simple app and data is coming from the server .

Comment: Try replacing the 3rd line with this: `let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonURL, options: .mappedIfSafe)` where `jsonURL` has the URL to your server

Comment: code is giving me the error :   Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'                                                                at this line :  staffNameLabel.text = jsonDriverDetails["Staff_Name"] as? String

Comment: that problem seems to come from this line `if let jsonDriverDetails = json["Driver_Details"] as? [[String: Any]]` casting the first and only element in your json. Try debugging your code, stop in that line and inspect your `json` object. It should be exactly the same as in your question.

Comment: error is gone but its not showing any data into label.now what should I do?  :(

Comment: while debugging check that you really have a String from this line: `jsonDriverDetails["Staff_Name"] as? String`. If you are updating a UILabel in a TableView, you need to call `tableView.reloadData()` otherwise check that `staffNameLabel` is connected to a UILabel in your Storyboard

Comment: thank you so much pesch for help :) will let you know if there is any issue.

Comment: hey can you please send me your mail details so that will ping you my code coz I can't figure out which step m missing.

Comment: If you are getting the data from a server, you don't need the first `if let path...` . You will get the `jsonData` using `try Data(contentsOf:...` or better yet using URLSession dataTask. Once you get data back from either of those run it through `if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data...`